# Android PTPP VPN session stalling after precisely 30-31 minutes

Tags: networking, vpn

My Android 4.2.2 device (MINIX neo X5 TV-box) uses PTPP VPN connection to Netflix via a HideMyAss VPN server. The problem is that the Netflix session always stalls precisely 30-31 minutes after the VPN connection was established, claiming there is no data connection, although the VPN status (in android settings) says "connected". It works again (for another 30-31 minutes) when I disconnect and reconnect the VPN connection. 
I usually take the occasion to get myself a new cold beer, but it adds up :) does anybody have an idea how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Does the rest of the Internet work? Or is it just the Netflix service?

In any case, contact your VPN service provider for advise. As long as the VPN connection is not terminated (as you say it isn’t) any problem is likely to be much easier debugged on the service providers side. You have noticed a pattern, and that should be debuggable for them.

Comment: The intire internet connection (not just netflix) goes down until I disconnect or reconnect the VPN.

As suggested, I  have now contacted the VPN provider HideMyAss, let's see what they say.